# Canned tomatoes with too much vinegar

Tags: tomatoes, canning

I canned some tomatoes using vinegar but now the taste in my pasta sauce is too acidic. Is there anything I can do to correct this in my sauce?

Comment: Baking soda. Middle school chemistry.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a dash of liquid honey: it's a complex sugar that doesn't need much to combat an acidic taste.  If you have no liquid honey and the pasta sauce is still hot enough, use solid honey. if you have neither, use molasses, then cane sugar and if you only have white refined sugar, use that instead.

In all cases, stir well before tasting as you'll end up with ketchup if you add too much!

#### ;-)

Comment: Fabby, I need a chemist - could you ping me in the FP, please, if you have a moment? (Personal favour, not site-related.)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of sugar being used in tomato sauces to combat acidity from underripe or out of season tomatoes. Could be worth a try. :)